# How to get numpy ndarray from file of datetimes and to plot the differences with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm a numpy newbie, using numpy 1.10.2 and Python 2.7.6 on Linux. I have a file of 17M datetimes, like `"2015-12-24 03:39:02.012"`.
I want to plot the differences, `d[n]-d[n-1]`, as a function of time.

What is the numpy-ish way to get a darray from this file, and then some matplotlib way to plot diff vs. datetime (doesn't matter if diff `n-1` or `n+1`)?

I don't need a blinding speed hack; I'd rather learn the idiomatic numpy techniques.

Data looks like:

```
2015-12-24 03:39:02.009
2015-12-24 03:39:02.012
2015-12-24 03:39:02.015
2015-12-24 03:39:02.018
2015-12-24 03:39:02.021
2015-12-24 03:39:02.024
2015-12-24 03:39:02.027
2015-12-24 03:39:02.030
2015-12-24 03:39:02.033
2015-12-24 03:39:02.036
2015-12-24 03:39:02.039
2015-12-24 03:39:02.042
2015-12-24 03:39:02.045
2015-12-24 03:39:02.048
2015-12-24 03:39:02.051
2015-12-24 03:39:02.054
2015-12-24 03:39:02.057
2015-12-24 03:39:02.060
2015-12-24 03:39:02.063
2015-12-24 03:39:02.066
```

... 17M lines

So, to be clear, I want to plot something like

```
datetime64(2015-12-24 03:39:02.009), 3 # second datetime-first datetime
datetime64(2015-12-24 03:39:02.012), 3 # third datetime-second datetime
datetime64(2015-12-24 03:39:02.015), 3 # fourth datetime-third datetime
```

...

What I'm really looking for is spikes in the interval and what time the spikes happened.

Comment: can you use pandas? this is wonderfully easy in pandas

Comment: I have pandas installed, haven't tried it yet.  Pandas solution would be welcome, though I also hope to learn some raw numpy.

Comment: Cool. Now post 10-20 lines of your file so people have something to test our.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can read the file in one line:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', header=None, parse_dates=[0], names=['date'])
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Calculate the difference

```
diff = df[1:] - df.shift()[1:]
```

Plot the result:

```
plt.plot(df[1:], diff.values)
```

[image]

You can convert the values into seconds:

```
seconds = diff.date.get_values().astype(float) / 1e9
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks!  Now I need to get the y values in seconds, like 0.00315, 0.00300, etc.

Comment: This is just one line. Added.